# Disallow UIScrollView from catching subviews touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview

I've got a `UIScrollView` covered with a custom `UIView` which desperatly needs to listen to all the touch events that happen inside of him.

At first, all I was getting was `touchesBegan:` and `touchesCancelled:` events. No `touchesMoved:`, no `touchesEnded:`. In fact, all the dragging gestures where being canceled by the above `UIScrollView`. This was solved by the following setting:

```
_scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
```

Now, the behaviour changes depending on the "length in time" of the first touch on the UIView. If it's short, then the relative dragging is managed as it was a scroll for the `UIScrollView`. If it's long, then I'm getting the `touchesMoved:` events inside my UIView.

What I want is to always receive `touchesMoved:` inside my UIView. How can I make it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried modifying the `delaysContentTouches` property of your `UIScrollView`? I had a similar issue, solved it.