# UIScrollView sending touches to subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiscrollview

**Note:** I already read some questions about the `UIScrollView` sending touches to the subviews ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725721/disallow-uiscrollview-from-catching-subviews-touches) included and although I have up voted, it's not working as I intended anymore).

**What I have:** I have a `UIScrollView` with a Custom `UIView` (let's call it **A**) inside which covers the entire `UIScrollView`. I am also allowed to put other custom `UIViews` inside the **A**.

On the code I am doing this:

```
[scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
```

**What is happening:** At the moment my only issue is that, if I want to move a subview inside **A**, I have to touch it, wait, and then move it. Exactly as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725721/disallow-uiscrollview-from-catching-subviews-touches):

> Now, the behaviour changes depending on the "length in time" of the
>   first touch on the UIView. If it's short, then the relative dragging
>   is managed as it was a scroll for the UIScrollView. If it's long, then
>   I'm getting the touchesMoved: events inside my UIView.

**What I want:** The subviews inside **A** should always receive priority and I shouldn't have to touch and wait. If I touch **A** and not a subview of it, I want the `UIScrollView` to receive the touches, like panning and moving around (the `contentSize` is bigger than the `frame`).

---

**Edit 1.0**

The only reason for me to have this **A** view inside a generic `UIScrollView`, is because I want to be able to zoom in/out on the **A** view. So I am doing the following:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return customView; // this is the A view
}
```

In the beginning I didn't had the **A** view inside the `UIScrollView` and the only thing I did was adding the **A** as a subView of my `UIViewController's` root view and everything went well. **If there is another way to enable zoom in/out I will gladly accept the answer.**

Comment: Just quick googling, tried to override scrollView's `hitTest` ? http://www.herbert-siojo.com/2011/04/01/forwarding-touches-to-subviews-of-uiscrollview/

Comment: Already seen this suggestion, doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to add UIGestureRecognizer to the scrollview and then check touch is locationInView is in custom uiview ...

Comment: The **A** view is covering all the screen. So the A screen is always going to be returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note:** Thank you all for your contributions, specially to Aaron Hayman.

I was able to figure it out by doing the following on the `UIScrollView` sub-class I had:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
   CGPoint pointOfContact = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self];

    // The view with a tag of 200 is my A view.
    return (![[self hitTest:pointOfContact withEvent:nil] isEqual:[self viewWithTag:200]]);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I should have recommended subclassing UIScrollView.  I would add though that you might need to differentiate between the `UIScrollView`'s gesture recognizers.  For instance, you might want to cancel taps and pans, but not pinches (to zoom).  It might be disconcerting to have pinching not work occasionally, when `locationInView` returns a point within one of your subviews.  You should be able to easily do this with something like: `if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]) return YES;`.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this, but I believe how you are handling the touch events in View A (or it's subviews) will determine how touch events are passed on.  Specifically, if you're trying to use the methods: `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoves`, `touchesEnded`, etc instead of a `UIGestureRecognizer` you won't receive the touches in the way you want.  Apple design the `UIGestureRecognizer` to handle problems like the one you're facing.  Specifically, the `UIScrollView` uses `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to handle the scrolling.  If you add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to each of the subviews of `View A` any "panning" that occurs on one of those subviews should be sent to that subview instead of the `UIScrollView`.  However, if you're simply using the "raw" `touches` methods, the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in `UIScrollView` will never be cancelled.

In general, it's almost always best to use a `UIGestureRecognizer` instead of processing the touches directly in the view.  If you need touches processed in a way that no standard `UIGestureRecognizer` can provide, subclass `UIGestureRecognizer` and process the touches there. That way you get all the the functionality of a `UIGestureRecognizer` along with your own custom touch processing. I really think Apple intended for `UIGestureRecognizer` to replace most (if not all) of the custom touch processing code that developers use on `UIView`. It allows for code-reuse and it's a lot easier to deal with when mitigating what code processes what touch event.

Answer (score 1):

Jacky, I needed a similar thing: Within a building plan (your A, in my case a subclass of UIScrollView), let the user place and resize objects (call them Bs). Here's a sketch of what it took me to get at this behavior:

- In the superview's (A) `initWithFrame:` method, set these two:

  ```
  self.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
  self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
  ```

  This will ensure taps on B are immediately routed to the Bs.
- In the embedded B, stop the superview A from cancelling taps, so it does not interfere with a gesture started on the B.

  In the `touchesBegan:` method, search the view hierarchy upwards (using `superview` property of the views) until you find a `UIScrollView`, and set its `canCancelContentTouches` to `NO`. Remember the superview you changed, and restore this property in the `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled` methods of B.

I'd be interested whether this works for you as well. Good Luck!

nobi

Comment: I had that before and worked well.. The issue is that I wanted to enable zoom in/out with the pan gesture... And for that I needed to put the **A** view inside a UIScrollView so I could call this method: `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you had better use "touchesBegan,touchesMoved,touchesEnded" to pass the event.

you can do like this:

you should make a mainView . It has 2 property. One is yourScrollView A , and One is yourCustomView.

```
`[yourScrollView addSubviews:yourCustomView];
[mainView addSubviews:yourScrollView];`
```

and then write your touches method in the mainView.m like this (ignor the scrollView statment)

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
   if ([[touches allObjects] isKindOfClass:[yourCustomView class]]) 
   {

        //do whatever you want
   }

}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
   if ([[touches allObjects] isKindOfClass:[yourCustomView class]]) 
   {
       //do whatever you want
   }
}
```

The last step: pass the event to the subview of the scrollView(your A).

```
#import "yourScrollView.h"


@implementation yourScrollView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if(!self.dragging)
        [[self nextResponder] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    if(!self.dragging)
        [[self nextResponder] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    if(!self.dragging)
        [[self nextResponder] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

wish to help you

Comment: I have `UIScrollView` with a Custom `UIView` called A. The Custom `UIView` is called A and not the `UIScrollView`. This `UIScrollView` **is just used** for me to be able to zoon in/out on the A.

Comment: Sending events directly to the next responder is discouraged by apple