# UIScrollView pass event to child chain on WillEndDragging

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview

**Edit:** I am editing my initial question (see below for history) as I am getting new information.

I figured out that when the swipe motion starts from inside the button bounds, we never receive `TouchesEnded` or `TouchesCancelled`, only `TouchesMoved`. However, if I can react on `WillEnddragging`, it would be great. Is it possible to cancel a gesture on `WillEndDragging` and also pass this cancel down the children chain?

---

History:

I am using Xamarin Forms and I have the following issue
I have custom controls part of native scrolling views, like ScrollView or CollectionView, that remain in "clicked" state after the finger enters them but then initiates a scroll gesture.

I had a similar issue on UWP in the past and managed to solve it with the [UIElement.PointerCaptureLost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointercapturelost?view=winrt-22621) event.

Sorry if I am wasting your time on trivial stuff, but I am really stuck and I greatly appreciate your help.

I have tried different approaches suggested, including setting `DelaysContentTouches` to NO, and playing around with `CanCancelContentTouches` and overriding `TouchesShouldCancelInContentView` to always return NO, in a ScrollView custom renderer.

I have had a read of
[Allow UIScrollView and its subviews to both respond to a touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485100/allow-uiscrollview-and-its-subviews-to-both-respond-to-a-touch)
and
[UIScrollView sending touches to subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947797/uiscrollview-sending-touches-to-subviews)

Maybe the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947797/uiscrollview-sending-touches-to-subviews) helps, but I am not sure how to get the tag of my custom view.

What I am expecting is my custom controls to receive the cancelled touch event (or something similar) as happens in both Android and Windows

Comment: I think you need to provide the code for one of your "custom controls" ... it's very possible you are missing some event handling.

Comment: @DonMag The controls work as expected on the other platforms (Android and UWP currently). In Android, I see in the DispatchTouchEvent() method, the `MotionEvent.ActionMasked` is of type `MotionEventActions.Cancelled`.

It could be very much the case that my iOS UIGestureRecognizer is missing something, but as I understand the only montion capturing methods I have are `TouchesBegan`, `Moved`, `Exited` and `Cancelled`. Unfortunately `TouchesCancelled` does not fire at this case, and I was wondering how other devs do it.

I'm sorry I cannot include much code, this is a work project

Comment: It would, of course, be easier if you could put together a minimal example of what you're doing for a custom control... Have you also implemented `touchesEnded`?

Comment: Did you add Gesture Recognizers to your view? They could interfere with TouchesCancelled.

Comment: @DonMag yes I have. However, I see from debugging that when the issue occurs, the last Touches method that fires is `TouchesMoved`. So, to fix the issue, I send a "Released" event, when a button receives `TouchesMoved`. However, this is not optimal, as then the button might be unresponsive. Looks to me like the touch events get "lost" somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easier than it looked. Solved by adding a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to my `UIGestureRecognizer` class and in the delegate I overwrote `ShouldRecognizeSimultaneously` to return `true`.